# How to find how many times a WCF Service is called by a client

Tags: performance, wcf

I am trying to send a message from my client application to my WCF service for a given time span
What what I wanted to find out is how many times my WCF service is hit by a client.

Here is a client application:

```
var messages = new String[1];
messages[0] = "My simple request";
  var client2 = new Operator();
var startTime = DateTime.Now;
var timeoutSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(.06);
var count =0;

while ((DateTime.Now - startTime) <= timeoutSpan)
{
    foreach (string message in messages)
    {
        txtRequest.Text = message;
        sendMessageResult = client.sendMessage("02", txtRequest.Text);
        count++;
    }
}

// this counts how many request I sent 
textBox1.Text = count.ToString();
// this shows the server side count
textBox2.Text = client2.TotalHits().ToString();
```

Here is my WCF service application

**EDIT:**

```
  public byte sendMessage(string strMsgId, string strMessage)
  {
   byte result = 1;

    try
    {
       if (strMsgId == "02") 
       {

        lock (_lock)
                {
                    ++_count;
                }
          // Logging-------
          // Build timestamp string
          var currentDateTime = DateTime.Now;
          string timeStampString = currentDateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hhmmssfff");

          // Build filename for Inbound messages, concat timestamp and .txt extension.
          string debugFileName = "C:\\Inboundmessage" + " " + timeStampString + ".txt";
          var inboundMessageLog = new StreamWriter(debugFileName, false, System.Text.Encoding.Default);

          // Write to the file:
          inboundMessageLog.WriteLine(DateTime.Now);
          inboundMessageLog.WriteLine("Time = {0}", currentDateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss:fff tt"));
          inboundMessageLog.WriteLine("{0}{1}{2}", "Inbound Message:", Environment.NewLine, strMessage);
        inboundMessageLog.WriteLine("{0}{1}", "count:", _count);
          inboundMessageLog.Close();

          // --------------
          result = 0;
      }
}
catch
{
    //Failed
    result = 1;
}
return result;
```

// Here is a count method

```
   public int TotalHits()
    {
        return _count;
    }
```

I see in the log the count is >0 but why on client side I dont see the change when I call the TotalHit method?

Comment: Do you just care that is called or that is called by some specific client for which you have to record some audit data?

Comment: It is called by my client and I want to record the audit data

Comment: see this [WCF Extensibility – IOperationBehavior article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2011/04/12/wcf-extensibility-ioperationbehavior.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

A question:
What exactly are you trying to achieve here?

The solution is two steps:
Step 1: Enable session at the IService

```
[ServiceContract()]
public interface IService
{
    [OperationContract]
    string SayHello(string toWhom);

    [OperationContract]
    int TotalHits();

}
```

Step 2: Add a ServiceBehavior tag to enable Singleton

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode=InstanceContextMode.Single)]
public Service: IService
{
    int count;
    object _lock = new object();

    string SayHello(string toWhom)
    {
        lock(_lock) { ++count; }

        return "Hello, " + toWhom;
    }

    int TotalHits()
    {
        return count;
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to know how many times the operation in my wcf service is called. I want to add a counter.

Comment: updated the code. Keywords here are `InstanceContextMode.Single` and the `lock` rest all is pretty obvious. Why do you need to count btw?

Comment: I wanted to count how many times it has been called from two clients pointing to it(same service) for a time span i set in the above code.

Comment: and I want to count how many times it is called at the service level not from my client side

Comment: may I ask why you add the lock object is it to insure you are counting per a single client call and return the total hit per/call? what if you want to call that service from two clients ?

Comment: it makes it thread safe. so when two clients call the service at a time you would be sure that they don't over write other's change.

Comment: Thanks Ziaullah I updated my code to see the count. I called the TotalHits method from my client to display count but the number never changes.